# Delete files with filenames longer than x

Tags: batch-file, filenames, delete-file, buffer-overrun

I am looking for some help creating a BAT file to help delete videos and images over a certain filename length.

A bit of background:

We have a custom made application and we do not have the source code. it updates its videos from a feed. recently we have been getting "buffer overrun detected" errors. we believe that the file names longer than 90 characters are becoming an issue.

I would like to remove these WMV and JPG files before they become a problem. We usually use bat files to perform these small tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't stick to something OS -specific, use scripting language that would run on any platform, e.g. Node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");

var folderName = __dirname;  // for current folder
var maxlength = 90;

function getFiles(dir, files_) {
    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for ( var i in files) {
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else {
            files_.push(name);
        }
    }
    return files_;
}

var files = getFiles(folderName);
console.log(files);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    filename = files[i];
    if (filename.length > maxlength) {
        console.log("Deleting " + filename);
        fs.unlinkSync(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i would just paste something like this in a text file and save it as a javascript file? with the edits added of course

Comment: When I type `node delete90.js` this message appears: "node" is not recognized as an internal or external command... etc. I use Windows 8.1 64 bits...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.WMV *.JPG) do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   if "!filename:~90!" neq "" (
      ECHO del "%%a"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

without external tools (not tested):

```
@echo off

rem:::: set the correct directory
set "rootdir=c:\somewhere"
pushd "%rootdir%"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%# in (*.WMV *.JPG) do (

    call ::strlen0 "%%~nx#" len
    if !len! GEQ 90 (
        rem:::: remove the echo if the correct files are listed
        echo del /q /f "%%~nx#"
    )

)

endlocal



exit /b 0
:strlen0  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b
```

Pay attention to the comments - these are the places you need to alter your script.